# Heatmap (ggplot): time versus date

Tags: r, ggplot2, kde-plasma

I have some sample data (actually these are crime data):

```
randomDatetime <- function(N, st="2018/01/01", et="2018/12/31") {
st <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(st))
et <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(et))
dt <- as.numeric(difftime(et,st,unit="sec"))
ev <- sort(runif(N, 0, dt))
rt <- st + ev
return(rt)
}

df <- data.frame(date=randomDatetime(1000))
```

Now, I'd like to create a KDE-plot / heatmap like this:

[image]

On the x-axis there should be the dates (2018-01-01 to 2018-12-31) and on the y-axis there should be the time (00:00-23:59). The goal is to show at what times during the day certain crime types happen most often and if there are differences between the saisons etc.

Now, I am having problems with the y-axis as I dont know how to save times only. I could calculate the number of minutes since midnight for example, but this does not seem very elegant to me.

I guess it should be like:

```
ggplot(aes(x = date, y = ??) data = df) + 
geom_density_2d()+
scale_x_date(date_breaks = "months", date_labels = "%m", limits=as.Date(c("2018-01-01","2018-12-31")))
```

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a more concise way, but this works:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

randomDatetime <- function(N, st="2018/01/01", et="2018/12/31") {
  st <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(st))
  et <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(et))
  dt <- as.numeric(difftime(et,st,unit="sec"))
  ev <- sort(runif(N, 0, dt))
  rt <- st + ev
  return(rt)
}

df <- data.frame(date=randomDatetime(1000)) %>% 
  mutate(dt = as.Date(str_sub(date, end=10)),
         time = str_sub(date, start=12),
         tm = as.numeric(hms(str_sub(date, start=12))))


ggplot(df, aes(x = dt, y=tm)) +
  stat_density_2d(aes(fill = stat(level)), geom = "polygon") +
  labs(x="Date", y="Time", fill=NULL) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(as.POSIXct((x), origin = Sys.Date(), tz = "UTC"), "%H:%M:%S")) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image: density plot]

Comment: Well done! Note you can directly use `scale_y_time()`. If you want to modify the x-axis, you can tinker with the implicit `scale_x_date()`. Also note you can cast much more directly: `mutate(dt = as.Date(date), tm = hms(str_sub(date, start=12))))`

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be with `lubridate`...

```
library(lubridate)
ggplot(aes(x = date, y = hour(date) + minute(date) / 60), data = df) + 
     geom_density_2d()
```